# codeigniter - populate dropdown list with query result using json

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter, select

I have a dropdown list, that when changed passes the value to a controller.

This controller, through the model then runs a query that returns multiple results.

I need to somehow populate my dropdown list with the results of the query.

my syntax is:

**Controller**

```
  function GetDeliveryAddressfromCustomer(){

    $this->load->model('Sales_model');
    if (isset($_POST['data'])){
        $q = strtolower($_POST['data']);
        $data = $this->Sales_model->GetDeliveryAddressfromCustomer($q);
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data));
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
  function GetDeliveryAddressfromCustomer($q){
    $this->db->select('deliveryaddress');
    $this->db->where('Account', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('Client');
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
            $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['deliveryaddress'])); 
       }
       return $row_set;
    }
  }
```

**View JS**

```
 $.post('GetDeliveryAddressfromCustomer', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) { 
  var selcust = selectedObj.value;

  //what to put here to pupulate dropdown list

  });
```

**View select**

```
 <select id="deliveryaddress" name="deliveryaddress" data-mini="true" data-theme="a">
   <option value="0"></option>
 </select>
```

the error is:  `Trying to get property of non-object`

I presume the error is from the multiple results being returned. selectedObj.value is an array not a value.

I am less worried about the part of pupulating the dropdown but if you have advice please provide it.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: is that the complete error? no line number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please post your json object as i dont know what your data output look like

but anyhow check this out

```
$.post('GetDeliveryAddressfromCustomer', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) { 
  var selcust = selectedObj.value;

  //what to put here to pupulate dropdown list
 $("#deliveryaddress").html('<option value=""></option>'); //or you could empty it or ignore this line
$.each(result, function(index, value) {
  $("#deliveryaddress").append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>')
            });
        }
        , "json"  //dont forget this
                );
```